# Problems unpickling object

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, pickle

I have this pickled object which I want to open but the idle is returning the error

```
TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes
```

Here is my code

```
openPrimorial = ('Primorial_pickled.txt','rb')
primorial = pickle.load(openPrimorial)
openPrimorial.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to call the open() method. Your current code simply creates a tuple of two values; it doesn't open any file.

Comment: Crap, how did I not notice that, i knew it was something simple. Thanks :)